# Magento keeps deleting canvas tag in CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9

When I put a canvas tag into Magento (for example create a test page with `<canvas></canvas>` as content), Magento keeps removing it automatically. How do I prevent this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update your question to include whether you make use of the WYSIWYG editor or not.

Comment: Where do you do what? As @mam08ixo said, please edit your question and add even more informations. Where do you add what, when it is removed, what do you expect...

Comment: I had WYSIWYG on. I did not mention it since I did not know it has such crucial impact, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to prevent this issue is to disable "Enable WYSIWYG Editor". You can do it via Admin panel under System>>Content Management.

Comment: "Disabled by default" works for me. I can still use the wysiwyg when needed that way.

Comment: Disabling WYSIWYG worked for me, I thank you sincerely.